# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instapy

I've found some possible answers on internet but none seemed to work. Does anyone know what is going wrong?

The code:

```
""" Quickstart script for InstaPy usage """

# imports
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run
from instapy import set_workspace

username='test'
password='test'

excluders = ["friend1", "friend2", "friend3"]

# get an InstaPy session!
session = InstaPy(username=username,
                  password=password,
                  headless_browser=True,
                  geckodriver_path='/usr/local/Cellar/geckodriver/0.27.0/bin/geckodriver')

with smart_run(session):
    session.set_dont_include(excluders)
    session.set_do_follow(enabled=True, times=1)

    session.follow_user_followers(['account1', 'account2', 'account3'], amount=10, randomize=False, sleep_delay=60)
```

The error message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

I'm using mac, Python 3.7 & instapy 0.6.10

Comment: geckodriver_path='/usr/local/Cellar/geckodriver/0.27.0/bin/geckodriver add the .exe I think this is what's causing it.

Comment: Yeah I thought that might have been the problem as well but it didn't help. I installed firefox through brew and then it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I brew installed firefox and then it worked